# Why cant I refer to a random index in my 4D list, while I know it exists?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, dimensions

I got a 4D list, and I want where I want to display only the [k][3][j][z], but this isnt working. I checked all the counts and they are all 5+, so 3[4] should work...

```
for (int k = 0; k < lijst4D.Count; k++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lijst4D[k].Count; i++) // This count is higher than 4!
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lijst4D[k][i].Count; j++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < lijst4D[k][i][j].Count; z++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lijst4D[k][i][j][z]); // This is working
                Console.WriteLine(lijst4D[k][3][j][z]); // This is NOT working
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This isnt working either:

```
Console.WriteLine(lijst4D[0][0][0][0]);
Console.WriteLine(lijst4D[1][1][1][1]);
```

Why isnt this working? Can anyone explain me? Am I missing something?

I get this error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index`

EDIT: this IS working tho.. why?

```
for (int k = 0; k < lijst4D.Count; k++)
{
    for (int i = 3; i < 4; i++) // Will do this loop once
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lijst4D[k][i].Count; j++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < lijst4D[k][i][j].Count; z++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lijst4D[k][i][j][z]); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT2: How I fill up my lists:

```
for (int g = 0; g < List.Count; g++)
{
    List<List<List<string>>> Lijst3D = new List<List<List<string>>>();
    for (int j = 0; j < Alist.Count; j++)
    {
        List<List<string>> Lijst2D = new List<List<string>>();
        for (int k = 0; k < Anotherlist.Count; k++)
        {
            List<string> Lijst1D = new List<string>();
            Lijst2D.Add(Lijst1D);
        }
        Lijst3D.Add(Lijst2D);
    }
    Lijst4D.Add(Lijst3D);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks very similar to the question you've posted few days ago. Frankly, "working or not" strictly depends on how do you filling your array. It's hard to say more without seeing it.

Comment: One second, I will add the code where I show you how I fill up my 4Dlist

Comment: I added the code where I add the lists to the list etc

Comment: @AndyKorneyev I did add the filling of my array to the questoin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code where you're filling your 4D list:

```
List<string> Lijst1D = new List<string>();
Lijst2D.Add(Lijst1D);
```

Here you're creating new `List<string>` and adding it to parent 2D list.

But `Lijst1D` itself doesn't contains any elements (you haven't added anything to it), so `Lijst4D[0]` will throw that `IndexOutOfRangeException` as well as `Lijst4D[0][0][0][0]` throws it.

Comment: True, I add it this way to my code: Lijst4D[x][y][z].Add("test");

Comment: But isnt it weird that this works: `for (int i = 3; i < 4; i++)` But thi doenst: `Console.WriteLine(lijst4D[k][3][j][z]);` ? Or is that totally understandable? :)

Comment: @wouter Nothing weird here. `Lijst4D[k][i][j].Count` is zero (since you're not adding anything to `List1D`), so most inner loop you've provided in your "this IS working" example `for (int z = 0; z < lijst4D[k][i][j].Count; z++)` simply doesn't executing at all - that's why you're not getting exception.

Comment: Andy, I wanna thank you for answering my question. Good day

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with a 4-dimensional (A[a,b,c,d]) array or 4D jagged arrays (array where each element is pointing to another array and so on)?
Seems like you want to work with a 4D array ( access it like A[i,j]) but instead your code is accessing a jagged array (like A[i][j])

Edit:
I would break the List into a proper data structure which I can visualize properly...may be something like this...
You can add a method in each class to populate its list container in turn...

```
void Main()
{
    var lstOuter= new List<A>();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class A
{
    public A ()
    {
        ListB=new List<string>();
    }
    public string val{get; set;}
    public List<string> ListB { get; set; }
}

class B
{
    public B ()
    {
        ListC=new List<string>();
    }
    public string val{get; set;}
    public List<string> ListC { get; set; }
}


class C
{
    public C ()
    {
        ListD=new List<string>();
    }
    public string val{get; set;}
    public List<string> ListD { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I am working with a list, and I actually dont know, let me add the code where I add how I fill my list

Comment: I added the code where I add the lists to the lists etc.. If i trued A[i,j] It will tell me code has to take 4arguments